# Converting a list into a term in Prolog

Tags: prolog

What is the best way of converting a Prolog list into a Prolog term (that is not a list), in terms of
efficiency, and using existing built-in predicates as much as possible?

The interface and usage examples would be the following.

```
%% list_to_term(+List:list, +Functor:atom, -Term:term)
%
% Usage:
%
% ?- list_to_term([], myfunctor, Term).
% Term = myfunctor.
%
% ?- list_to_term([a, b, [c], D, 2], myfunctor, Term).
% Term = myfunctor(a, b, [c], D, 2).
```

I.e. the given list (which is actually a nested term) is flattened into
a term with the given name.

I'm not saying that it makes sense to do this. (But if you think that it does, please provide a usecase in your answer.)

Comment: What should be the answer for `list_to_term([X,Xs], '.', Term)`? You demand that it should not be a list ... :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. ;) Now that I read this question after 3 years it doesn't really make sense to me as it is. I would delete it altogether if I could.

Comment: It is a question from a beginner's perspective. Here is the place for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `=..` operator, like so:

```
list_to_term(List, Functor, Term) :-
    Term =.. [Functor | List].
```

Comment: You mean: Term =.. [Functor | List]?

Comment: @Kaarel: Oh, yeah.  I misread your example.  You are correct: in order to get the results you want, you need to use [Functor | List].