# Prolog list to comma separated string

Tags: string, list, prolog

I have a list like `[apple, orange]`and I want to convert it to a string like `"apple,orange"` in Prolog. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please explain why do you want to do that? Do you want to pretty-print the list? Do you want to serialize it into a file? And what is the nature of the input list: can it contain other lists or complex terms, can it contain variables and variable sharing?

Answer (score 7):

In SWI-Prolog you can simply use `atomic_list_concat/3` and `atom_string/2`:

```
?- atomic_list_concat([apple, banana, oranges], ',', Atom), atom_string(Atom, String).

Atom = 'apple,banana,oranges',
String = "apple,banana,oranges".
```

Comment: This  works for lists of atoms, and it's convenient -- but if one of the elements is complex (as in [apple,ba(nana)], it errs.

Answer (score 4):

In SWI-Prolog you can use `with_output_to/2`. Below are two versions, one using `write/1` and the other `writeq/1`. It's not clear from your question what kind of behaviour your require.

```
?- List = [apple, 'ora\\nge'], with_output_to(codes(Codes), write(List)),
   format("~s", [Codes]).
[apple,ora\nge]
List = [apple, 'ora\\nge'],
Codes = [91, 97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 44, 111, 114|...].

?- List = [apple, 'ora\\nge'], with_output_to(codes(Codes), writeq(List)),
   format("~s", [Codes]).
[apple,'ora\\nge']
List = [apple, 'ora\\nge'],
Codes = [91, 97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 44, 39, 111|...].
```

Comment: @selda: Look up `with_output_to` in the SWI-Prolog manual: `help(with_output_to).`

Comment: Experimenting (because the documentation is nearly useless to me) I find that if you just run the first two clauses, `List = [apple, 'orange'], with_output_to(codes(Codes), writeq(List))`, it defines `Codes` as a list of numbers corresponding to `List`. The first, 91, must be the bracket character; the trailing `|` means there are more left unshown. `format()` then prints it to the screen, in some obscure language where `~s` means ... uh ...

Answer (score 2):

if you use swi-prolog you can also do the following:

1) use the string_to_list/2 (you can give a list and get a string or give a string and get a list). the problem is that it wont insert commas so you will have to insert commas between the elements of your list manually; something like

```
insert_commas([],[]).
insert_commas([H|T],[H,', '|TC]):-
   insert_commas(T,TC).
```

so your predicate would be something like:

```
list_string_with_commas(L,S):-
   insert_commas(L,LC),
   string_to_list(S,LC).
```

2)you can use swritef/3 and string_concat/3. swritef/3 works like writef/2 but instead of writing in the output it creates a string with the data.

```
list_string_with_commas([],"").
list_string_with_commas([H,T],S):-
    swritef(SH,"%t, ",[H]),
    list_string_with_commas(T,ST),
    string_concat(SH,ST,T).
```

you might want to do some tail recursion optimisations

Answer (score 1):

I am a Prolog novice - but this is what I came up with.

```
list_codes([], "").

list_codes([Atom], Codes) :- atom_codes(Atom, Codes).

list_codes([Atom|ListTail], Codes) :-
        atom_codes(Atom, AtomCodes),
    append(AtomCodes, ",", AtomCodesWithComma),
    append(AtomCodesWithComma, ListTailCodes, Codes),
    list_codes(ListTail, ListTailCodes).

list_string(List, String) :-
    ground(List),
    list_codes(List, Codes),
    atom_codes(String, Codes).

list_string(List, String) :-
    ground(String),
    atom_codes(String, Codes),
    list_codes(List, Codes).
```

which gives:

```
?- list_string([], S).
S = '' .

?- list_string([apple], S).
S = apple .

?- list_string([apple, orange], S).
S = 'apple,orange' .

?- list_string([apple, orange, peach], S).
S = 'apple,orange,peach' .
```

and:

```
?- list_string(L, '').
L = [] .

?- list_string(L, 'banana').
L = [banana] .

?- list_string(L, 'banana,litchi').
L = ['banana,litchi'] .
```

Comment: I have a question as well, I want to a predicate from this list. I have a list [apple,orange]. I try to make fruits(apple,orange). Can you help me?

Comment: @selda If you have a new question, then post it as a new question, not as a comment to an unrelated answer. This question is answered though already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612604/converting-a-list-into-a-term-in-prolog

Answer (score 1):

term_string (30 char min S.O.)

Comment: Hi @user10221289, could you please provide more explanation to your answer?

Comment: Apart from the explanation, please also consider adding a bit of example code to demonstrate the effect of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't have enough rep to add this comment to Gavin Lock's answer. Gavin's solution is good so far as it goes, but it should be tweaked to avoid giving duplicate answers (or, rather, a variation on the same answer). The problem is that a list with a single atom will unify to two clauses in list_codes/2: the second AND the third clause. (A list with a single element still has a tail, i.e. the empty list.) I believe only the second clause binding is desired. The third clause seems to be designed to be recursive for lists that still have at least two elements. Therefore I recommend changing this clause to be:

```
list_codes([Atom,Next|ListTail], Codes) :-
    atom_codes(Atom, AtomCodes),
    list_codes([Next|ListTail], ListTailCodes),
    append(AtomCodes, ",", AtomCodesWithComma),
    append(AtomCodesWithComma, ListTailCodes, Codes).
```

This will only unify when the list has at least two elements, and will prevent getting two solutions.