# Prolog: Convert constant with parentheses to string

Tags: prolog

I have question about Prolog. When I have the constant e.g. `fib(7)` and I want to convert it to a string with `atom_codes(fib(7), A)` I get the error, that for `fib(7)` a non numeric atom is expected.

Obviously the parentheses are the problem. What can i do?

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog then this will be of interest: [What type is a single quoted string?](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/what-type-is-a-single-quoted-string/1102)

Comment: I am using Ciao-Prolog, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of misunderstandings. `fib(7)` is not a "constant". It's a "term". It is also not an "atom". `atom_codes` (as its name implies) converts an *atom* to a list of character codes.

I'll give you some ideas on how to handle this problem, which I would have indicated in the comments, but it's much too long of a hint to do so. :)

You could write a predicate and use the `=../2` to break the term down. `=../2` unifies a term as its first argument with a list as its second where the *functor* of the term is the first element of the list, and the remaining elements are the arguments in the term.

If you know you are dealing with simple terms, then your predicate could look like this:

```
term_codes(Term, Codes) :-
    Term =.. [Functor | Arguments],
    atom_codes(Functor, Codes),
    (   Arguments = []
    ->  true    % Term is a simple atom
    ;   % Arguments is a list of atoms or more complex terms
        % For a simple argument list, you can use atom_list_concat 
    ).
```

See [Prolog list to comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879956/prolog-list-to-comma-separated-string) for an example of using `atom_list_concat` and, from there, you can use `atom_codes` for a list.

This is just my first thought on this problem. For now I'll leave the filling in of the details in the above if `Arguments` is not empty. If you are going to assume always a single, atomic argument, the predicate is very simple. However, if you can have an arbitrary number of arguments for your `Term`, then you'll need to process it as a list and concatenate the results of `atom_codes` for each argument and include a code for comma (`,`) in between each sequence of atom codes. The predicate becomes even more complex if your `Term` can be compound (*e.g.*, foo(1, bar(2, 3))`). I'm not sure which it is since it hasn't been specified in the question.

Using your `fib(7)` example, here's the concept:

```
fib(7) =.. [fib, [7]]
atom_codes(fib, [102, 105, 98])
atom_codes(7, [55]),
atom_codes('(', [40]),
atom_codes(')', [41]),
% result would be: [102, 105, 98, 40, 55, 41])
```